# How to use Summernote with ASP.net C# webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, summernote

I have included Summernote into an ASP.NET Webforms page, but when I apply `runat="server"`, the toolbar disappears. In fact the Summernote just appears as a textbox.

I'm using `runat="server"` so that I can reference it in the code behind to set/get the inner text. Not sure if that's the right, or wrong way to go about it?

I have included the js and css links/lines...

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
```

The following jquery/bootstrap lines are in the masterpage...

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And this is my html and javascript for Summernote...

```
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Body" class="myLargeFont"></asp:Label>
        <textarea id="summernote" name="summernote" runat="server" style="width:650px; height:550px;"></textarea>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstAttachments" runat="server" Visible="false" Height="200px" Width="150px"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnShowAttachment" runat="server" Text="Load" Visible="false" />
    </p>
```

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#summernote').summernote({
                placeholder: 'Hello Bootstrap 4',
                //tabsize: 2,
                height: 300,
                toolbar: [
                    // [groupName, [list of button]]
                    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['height', ['height']],
                    ['table', ['table']],
                    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                    ['view', ['codeview']]
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In the following screenshot, links are the outcome when setting runat="server", and without runat="server"...

[Without runat=server result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsuDq.jpg)

[With runat=server result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HYU4.jpg)

Comment: ...why on earth are you still using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: Depending on just how _ancient_ the version of WebForms is that you're running, when you add `runat="server"` to an element or WebControl, it will override the `id=""` attributes which breaks scripts - you can easily override this in ASP.NET 4 with `ClientIdMode=""` see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.8.1 - but a much better idea would be to migrate away from a dead platform that has been effectively-obsoleted since ASP.NET MVC came out in 2008 - that's 15 years ago...

Comment: We are using ASP.Net 4.8.  So should we use ClientIdMode="" instead of id=""?

Comment: @Dai - Thanks for the ClientIdMode="" tip, it appears to work.  I've set it to ClientIdMode="Static" to keep the original id.  However, I have another issue that probably need another question submitting.  But thanks!